# Nested FIRST_ARG macro

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I'm playing with C macros and I can't understand issue presented below.

```
#define FIRST_ARG(N, ...)   N

#define FIRST_ARG_EXPANDED(N, ...)   FIRST_ARG(N, __VA_ARGS__)

#define ELEMENTS(DEF, ...)  DEF(1, 2, 3), \
                            DEF(4, 5, 6)

int main()
{
    char array1[] = { FIRST_ARG(ELEMENTS(FIRST_ARG)) };
    char array2[] = { FIRST_ARG_EXPANDED(ELEMENTS(FIRST_ARG)) };
    printf("array1 size = %zu, array2 size = %zu \n", sizeof(array1), sizeof(array2));

    return 0;
}
```

It turns out that `array1` and `array2` differs. `FIRST_ARG(ELEMENTS(FIRST_ARG))` is expanded to `1, 4` while `FIRST_ARG_EXPANDED(ELEMENTS(FIRST_ARG))` result is `1`.

I do belive there is some explanation of that. Look at Eclipse step by step expansion:
[image]

Can someone find an explanation basing on the C standard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arguments are macro replaced first and not rescanned to separate them at commas, so a macro that becomes `1, 4` remains one argument. But, after a macro is replaced, the new sequence is rescanned, and commas separate arguments.

Per C 2018 6.10.3.1 1, the arguments of a macro are processed for macro replacement before the macro itself is replaced:

> … Before being substituted, each argument’s preprocessing tokens are completely macro replaced as if they formed the rest of the preprocessing file; no other preprocessing tokens are available.

So, in `FIRST_ARG(ELEMENTS(FIRST_ARG))`, we first replace `ELEMENTS(FIRST_ARG)`, which produces `FIRST_ARG(1, 2, 3), FIRST_ARG(4, 5, 6)`. This replacement is rescanned for further replacement, per 6.10.3.4 1:

> … The resulting preprocessing token sequence is then rescanned, along with all subsequent preprocessing tokens of the source file, for more macro names to replace.

That rescanning results in `FIRST_ARG(1, 2, 3), FIRST_ARG(4, 5, 6)` becoming `1, 4`. So, the result of processing the argument to that original `FIRST_ARG` is `1, 4`. Note that this is itself the entire first argument; it is not reprocessed so that the comma causes a separation of arguments—it takes its place as the value of the first parameter to `FIRST_ARG`. Then `FIRST_ARG` is replaced with this value of the argument, `1, 4`.

In `FIRST_ARG_EXPANDED(ELEMENTS(FIRST_ARG))`, we again replace the argument first, resulting in the argument `1, 4` as above, and then we have `FIRST_ARG_EXPANDED(1, 4)`. This is replaced with `FIRST_ARG(1, 4)`. Now that is scanned, and the tokens of `1, 4` become separate arguments to `FIRST_ARG`, so the result is the first argument, `1`.

In summary, the replacement of an argument of a macro produces one argument. If you want it to be rescanned for separation into multiple arguments at commas, you must use another macro.